# Find and update key values in a file using ansible role

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I need to update the key values using regex and replace like all user input ,username and password using a separate new task.

inventory/main.yml

```
service1 : abc.com/s1
service2 : def.com/s2
username : user
password: pass
```

values.yml

```
---
service1:
  image:
    name: <user input> # service1 image

service2:
  config:
    range: 127.0.0.0
  image:
    name: <user input> # service2 image
  id:
    username:  # DB username
    password:  # DB Password
```

Expectation :

values.yml

```
---
service1:
  image:
    name: abc.com/s1 # service1 image

service2:
  config:
    range: 127.0.0.0
  image:
    name: def.com/s2 # service2 image
  id:
    username: user # DB username
    password: pass # DB Password
```

**Should create a update_values.yml task which will find the values.yml path and replace the required values**

My attempt as update_values.yml

```
---
- name: update value
  replace:
    path: <path>/values.yml
    regexp: "service1.image.name: <user input>"
    replace: "abc.com/s1"
```

Comment: This is a requirement, not a question. Please edit your question to make it on topic showing what you have already done and the exact problem your are having by providing and [mcve](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In Ansible, this is a typical use-case of a [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-module-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host). Create the template

```yaml
shell> cat values.yml.j2
---
service1:
  image:
    name: {{ service1 }}  # service1 image

service2:
  config:
    range: 127.0.0.0
  image:
    name: {{ service2 }}  # service2 image
  id:
    username: {{ username }}  # DB username
    password: {{ password }}  # DB Password
```

Then, the tasks below

```yaml
    - include_vars: inventory/main.yml
    - template:
        src: values.yml.j2
        dest: values.yml
```

create the file

```yaml
shell> cat values.yml
---
service1:
  image:
    name: abc.com/s1  # service1 image

service2:
  config:
    range: 127.0.0.0
  image:
    name: def.com/s2  # service2 image
  id:
    username: user  # DB username
    password: pass  # DB Password
```

---

Q: ***"Is there any other method using regex and replace?"***

A: You can use [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-module-manage-lines-in-text-files) if you want to. For example

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: values.yml
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
        backrefs: true
      loop:
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)name: <user input>(.*)$', line: '\1name: {{ service2 }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)name: <user input>(.*)$', line: '\1name: {{ service1 }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)username:\s+.*?(\s+#.*)$', line: '\1username: {{ username }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)password:\s+.*?(\s+#.*)$', line: '\1password: {{ password }}\2'}
```

change the file

```yaml
shell> cat values.yml
---
service1:
  image:
    name: abc.com/s1 # service1 image

service2:
  config:
    range: 127.0.0.0
  image:
    name: def.com/s2 # service2 image
  id:
    username: user  # DB username
    password: pass  # DB Password
```

Comment: Is there any other method using regex and replace?    ,   
   service1.image.name: <user input>    , 
       I anyhow use this format only replacing <user input > with abc.com/s1    and username:   with   user   @vladimir-botka

Comment: You can try *lineinfile* if you want to. I added an example.

Comment: ^(\s*)name: <user input>(.*)$   how it will identify for service1 or service2 any specific line example service1.image.name like something this can you make it clear @vladimir-botka

Comment: Exactly! How? I'd like also to know. This was the reason for the *template*. Tell me once you learn this.

Comment: Is there any way using regex and replace method, should replace service1.image.name: <user input>  and service2.image.name: <user input>  to its value fetching from inventory @vladimir-botka

Comment: Yes. You've already said that. Show me how you use it in the replace method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244235/discussion-between-rowoc-and-vladimir-botka).